# Conversion to generic type

Tags: c#

I have following property in C#:

```
public T Value
{
    get
    {
        ClassImNotAllowedToChange.GetValue<T>();
    }
    set
    {
        ClassImNotAllowedToChange.SetValue<T>(value);
    }
}
```

For some reasons I can't change the implementation of `ClassImNotAllowedToChange`, it may impose some limitations on my part of code. The problem here is that I want to save and read `TimeSpan` as seconds amount, converted to `int`. And while I can easily write whatever I want in `setter`, `getter` restricts me to use only generic type `T`, which makes impossible something like this:

```
get
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(TimeSpan))
        return (T)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(ClassImNotAllowedToChange.GetValue<int>());

    return PlcItem.GetValue<T>();
}
```

There is no implicit conversion from `int` to `TimeSpan`, so the first code listing causes an `InvalidCastException` in runtime.
Is there any workaround to convert `int` to `TimeSpan` within `getter` or it's better to find another way of implementation?

Comment: Can you show us your initial attempt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As workaround you can cast `TimeSpan.FromSeconds` to `object` and then to `T` (with corresponding performance hit):

```
get
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(TimeSpan))
        return (T)(object)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(ClassImNotAllowedToChange.GetValue<int>());

    return PlcItem.GetValue<T>();
}
```

But I would recommend to rework your code somehow so you will not need to do this.

Comment: This workaround is for compile time, isn't it? OP say "in runtime".

Comment: @Sinatr as i understand OP has solution for runtime - it is `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(ClassImNotAllowedToChange.GetValue<int>())`

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what do you mean. `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(ClassImNotAllowedToChange.GetValue<int>())` causes a compile time exception, while this answer doesn't.

Comment: @ArliChokoev I mean that I assumed  that you already have desired behavior to "convert" `int` to `TimeSpan` in runtime (the code I mentioned in the comment), you needed one to make it compiling.